# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterble

Tags: python

I have the below code. Every time I run this I get the error

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable for the 'Number'.

```
f = open("E:\\vivek.txt","r")
waitstate = 0
Number = []
l_ines = []
l_ines=f.readlines()
#print(l_ines)
for i in l_ines:
    if len(i.split("# Waits"))>1:
        elements = []
        elements = ((i.split("# Waits")[1]).split(" "))
        for j in elements:
            if j!="":
                try:                    
                    Number = (int (j))
                    #Number = j
                    #print(Number)
                except:
                        pass
for i in Number:
    print(i)
```

Comment: `for i in Number:`, `Number` is an `int`. You probably want to `append` instead of set (`=`) `Number`...

Comment: Change `Number = (int (j))` to `Number.append(int (j))`

Comment: No change `Number = (int(j))` to `Number.append(int(j))`...

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Number = (int (j))
```

With

```
Number.append(int(j))
```

Because you already defined Number as a list, you can't then change it to an integer, you need to append the integer to the list.